# Button to paste from clipboard for all browsers

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, zeroclipboard

Is it possible create a button that can be used to paste some clipboard text into a textbox using javascript?
In my project I'm using ZeroClipboard to copy any text that I want, but now I need to paste that information using a single button in other page without any copy page connection.
At the internet I found ways to do that, but it just works on IE and I need a cross browser solution (minimun IE, chrome and FF).
Can anyone help me?

Other info:
I'm using asp.net mvc 3

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, Javascript don't have access to clipboard.
ZeroClipboard uses Flash in order to copy the text to clipboard BUT for security reasons too, Flash can only write to clipboard, not read.

The only way to do it is using a Java applet.

Comment: do you know where can I found a good sample to do this with applet?

Answer (score -1):

Here is article/Tutorial explaining how to do it : http://www.dynamic-tools.net/toolbox/copyToClipboard/

But the best pratice is to have a textarea with the data to copy already selected. Because some browser will not let you change the value of the clipboard data.

Comment: I don't want to copy, I already can do this with zeroClipboard, I want paste the info that already exists in clipboard into a textbox with a button click

Comment: He wants to paste, not to copy